# sbclからbashのオプションを渡すには？

Tags: bash, sbcl

sbclからシステムコマンドを実行する。

```lisp
(run-program "/bin/ls" nil :output T)
```

オプションの渡し方は

```lisp
(run-program "/bin/ls" '("-a") :output T)
```

こうだと知った。以下を実行したい時

```sh
$ printf \083c
```

こうしても、

```lisp
(run-program "/usr/bin/printf" '("\083c") :output T)
```

動かないのはなぜでしょうか。

Comment: `printf \083c` はこれで間違いはないのでしょうか？ もしかして `printf '\x08\x3c'` とか？ その場合、バックスラッシュ文字をエスケープする必要があります。`(run-program "/usr/bin/printf" '("\\x08\\x3c") :output T)` なお、bash や zsh では `printf` は builtin function(組み込み関数)になっています。